# How to limit the char size in a string stored as elements of an ArrayList in Java?

Tags: java, string, arraylist

I currently have an `ArrayList` of strings in Java, but I would like to truncate (or limit) the number of characters in each strings to 20. I couldn't find a method to do so.

Example:

```
"hello this is one of the descriptions in an array list, please limit me to 20"
```

should become:

```
"hello this is one of"
```

Comment: I don't think that this question really involves regular expressions. Are you sure that you want to list this as a tag?

Comment: Remember to use code points, not char units!!!!

Comment: @hovercarft removed the regex tag, thank you for noticing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some possible ways:

- Extend ArrayList and override its `add(...)` methods. I don't like this.
- Wrap your ArrayList and in the public methods that add or modify its contents, limit the number of characters. This idea I like much more!
- **Edit:** Or don't have an `ArrayList<String>` but instead an `ArrayList<MyCustomClass>` where MyCustomClass's constructor or setter methods truncate the Strings as needed. I like this one too!

Comment: Why do you prefer option 2 over option 1?

Comment: Because I tend to favor composition over inheritance. For instance, if the ArrayList is the nucleus for a model class in a MVC type design structure, then in my model setter methods, I'd truncate Strings before adding them to the ArrayList. The wrapper class, here the model itself, is the only class that needs to know about the truncation and have code that handles it. Since it is very unlikely that the model will need to expose all the methods of the ArrayList, there's no need for the class to extend ArrayList.

Comment: Same question as @rayd09 I understand what you are trying to do but in this context why option 2 is better...or its just your liking...:)?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels +1 (Death to non-interface LSP subtypes!) Are there any Interfaces that you'd implement on this wrapper, though?

Comment: @pst: loaded question, and I'm kind of shooting from the hip. How about `Iterator<T>`. You probably know better than i do though!

Comment: Maybe I should delete this answer and let @pst answer it, if he's going to start quoting Liskov and other OOP principles!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I don't actually use Java these days. Just wondering how you'd make it as "interchangeable" as possible. I like this answer (and your long comment).

Comment: @pst: I think that my answer is away from what the OP wanted. I'm guessing now that all he wanted was a for loop that uses `subString(...)`. I agree with making things interchangeable, and favor creating interfaces for many of my classes before creating the classes them self, but I'm no pro, and again, I have a feeling you know much more on this subject than I do.

Answer (score 2):

In the method that adds strings:

```
public void addString(String str) {
    String truncated = str != null ? str.substring(0, 20) : null;
    strings.add(truncated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do so by using [String.substring()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29). Example:

```
String str = "hello this is one of the descriptions in an array list, please limit me to 20";
String str20 = str.substring(0, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this a pre-existing list you want to alter:

```
public static void truncate20(List<String> strs) {
    for (ListIterator<String> iter = strs.listIterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
        String str = iter.next();
        if (str.length() > 20) {
            iter.set(str.substring(0, 20));
        }
    }
}
```

Creating a new list is easy enough - just `add` each iteration.

If you want to do it on insert, I suggest you write a class for it that **does not* extend `List`. Just give the operation you need that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You could also simply have an ArrayList of a custom class that is simply an array of up to 20 characters. The downside of course is that you're essentially re-implementing Java's String class